# Update Activity title from fragment in FragmentPagerAdapter

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-adapter, android-toolbar

I have `v4.ViewPager` inside `Activity` and use `SlidingTabLayout` from google's examples SlidingTabBasics. The problem I encounter is that each fragment retrieved from `getItem(position)` in `v4.FragmentPagerAdapter` has to **refresh activity title**. I have already learnt the hard way that `FragmentPagerAdapter` causes fragments to have really weird life callbacks so I can't probably use `onResume` or `onStart`. I noticed though that `onCreateOptionsMenu(menu,inflater)` gets called exactly when I want to refresh activity title. **Is there a callback to supply actions when `ViewPager` has settled the fragment and it should change activity title?**
Setting callback on `ViewPager.onPageSelected(position)` is inconvenient because I want this information to be propagated **from** fragment, not to fragment.

Currently I 'steal' `onCreateOptionsMenu(menu,inflater)` to do the work for me but it causes optimisation issues when no menu should be inflated but I still want the fragment to be able to affect activity title.

Comment: You want that title must depend upon fragment state, so simply change it whenever you want in code like button click or ViewPager fragment replace. It's not a big thing to worry about as you can change title anytime.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this code in your fragment:

```
if(getActivity() != null){
   getActivity().setTitle("new title");
}
```

Take into consideration that getActivity() will be null if the fragment is not yet attached to the activity.

Godspeed.

Comment: I have not put this clearly enough, but the problem is not HOW to set title, but WHEN - in previous design I had setTitle() in onCreate() of fragments and the result was that the title shown was generated by fragment that was  last created from adapter (for caching purposes), not the actual visible (settled).

Comment: This was my bad, I did not understand the question. PagerAdapter already takes care of the title, why does that not work for you?

Comment: It does but I need something that depends on fragment state - PagerAdapter can return title but it has no reference to fragment this title presents.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in different ways.
You can use interfaces in fragments that can be implemented by activity. But the drawback is, if you do have large number of fragments you must implement all of them.

Comment: I have direct access to hosting activity by calling getActivity(). Providing I didn't make a mistake about this activity instance class - I can do whatever I want with it. The problem is that FragmentPagerAdapter causes theirs fragments to be in OnResume() state even when they aren't in fact visible - when they are cached to be shown in response to user/from-code swipe.

Comment: If you do not want fragment caching and want to create it as a new fragment every time you swipe use        'FragmentStatePagerAdapter'